# Count same values on array using each Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I execute the query in the bank by the controller and I receive the data in the var when executing each on top of the var returns me an array, I wanted to count how many times the same parameter is repeated to create a counter could help me follow my code.

***Rails 3.2, ruby 2.3***

**results os my query.. from postgresql**

```
#<tickets title: "any text any first register ", updated_at: "2018-01-30 18:38:58", company: 89869> 

#<tickets title: "any text any second register ", updated_at: "2018-06-25 20:18:20", company: 99991>
```

I want to count how many times the same date is repeated regardless of the time to count the number of times that displays the same date.

Comment: You need to count a specific date or how many times each date repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific value you can use `count` method:

```
date = Date.today # Put your date here
tickets.count { |ticket| ticket.updated_at.to_date == date }
```

**UPD**

Group tickets by date and take the result from the hash. I am not sure if it works in Rails 3.2

```
date = Date.today # Put your date here
Ticket.group('date(updated_at)').size[date]
```

Comment: That means you would need to enumerate the array for each of its  elements, which is extremely inefficient.

Comment: But how you count suitable elements without enumerating them all? Only if we group tickets by date on DB level but it is a different approach.

Comment: tested, it worked fine is showing the count of equal dates after reading 20 records thankyou !!

Comment: Compare what you have with @max's solution (especially the use of [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally)). Both of the calculations he gives require a single pass through the array to obtain the counts for *all* unique elements in the array. You are making a pass through the array for each unique element in the array.

Comment: But this is the point. The question is how to count how many times the certain date is present. `count` method is made for this purpose, use `group_by` is overcomplication.

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach is to use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

```
counts_by_date = tickets.group_by do |ticket|
  ticket.updated.at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") # get Year/Month/Day as string
end.transform_values(&:count)
```

With Ruby 2.7 we get [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) which is slightly shorter:

```
counts_by_date = tickets.map do |ticket|
  ticket.updated.at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") # get Year/Month/Day as string
end.tally
```

Comment: undefined method `transform_values' for #<Hash:0x0000561021013038>

Comment: codevb, `Hash#transform_values` was introduced in Ruby v2.4. Does that explain your finding?

Comment: i want, count same date time was returning from postgresql using each.

Comment: Hmm, I've been doing this for years and have never seen the syntax where you chain a method off the `end` statement. I guess I've done similar things using the single line method `{ |x| something }.something_else`. I guess they're the same under the hood?

Comment: @Dan Yeah it is not the prettiest thing, but I prefer to be consistent and always use `do ... end` for multiline blocks anyway